# facebook graph user friends count

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

how can i get only how many friends have to user using facebook graph.
  * i dont want to get all the friends and then to count...i want to get from the api
    only the count of the friends .

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft having the `facebook` api.

have a look on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb932386.aspx